# How to implement SQLAlchemy Postgres async driver in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

I have come across really weird behavior implementing SQLAlchemy in my Django project using the asynchronous Postgres driver.

When I create a SQLAlchemy Session using a sessionmaker and then execute a simple SELECT statement within a session context manager, it generates the correct result the first time, but the proceeding attempts result in a RuntimeError exception stating "Task ... attached to a different loop". I looked up the error and it usually indicates that the session is persisted across multiple Django requests; however, in my code, I don't see how that is possible since I am creating the database session within the request using the sessionmaker and using the session context manager to close it.

It gets weirder when reloading the page for a 3rd time using the session context manager approach because the RuntimeError changes to an InterfaceError stating "cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress". But when not using the context manager approach and creating the session manually and immediately after using it closing the session it only produces the RuntimeError exception even after the 2nd attempt.

And it continues to get weird, when I do the second approach and do not await the session close, then it works completely fine other than a log message stating that the method was never awaited.

I have created a GitHub repository with a docker-compose.yml that reproduces the issue if anyone wants to see it for themselves.
https://github.com/enots227/Django-SQLAlchemy-Async

## Django Setup

#### settings.py

```py
# Database
DB_ENGINE = create_async_engine(URL.create(
    "postgresql+asyncpg",
    username=os.getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
    password=os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    host=os.getenv('DB_HOST'),
    port=os.getenv('DB_PORT'),
    database=os.getenv('DB_NAME')), echo=True)
DB_SESSION_MAKER = sessionmaker(DB_ENGINE, AsyncSession, expire_on_commit=False)
```

## Approach 1: Using Context Manager

Here is my code for the Django view for the context manager (http://127.0.0.1:8000/sql/1/)

```py
async def view1(request):
    html = '<html><body><ul>'

    async with settings.DB_SESSION_MAKER() as db_session:
        items = await list_accounts(db_session)

        for item in items:
            html += '<li>' + item.name + '</li>'

    html += '</ul></body></html>'

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

For the first execution, it returns back the correct response:

```html
<html><body><ul><li>test1</li></ul></body></html>
```

But if I try to reload the page after the first execution, it then raises a RuntimeError exception stating "Task ... attached to a different loop".

```
Internal Server Error: /sql/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 204, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 270, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/src/sql/views.py", line 12, in view1
    items = await list_accounts(db_session)
  File "/usr/src/app/src/sql/models.py", line 20, in list_accounts
    return await db_session.scalars(select(Account))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 269, in scalars
    result = await self.execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 212, in execute
    result = await greenlet_spawn(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 134, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1692, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2047, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(exc_info[1], with_traceback=exc_info[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 479, in execute
    self._adapt_connection.await_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 76, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 129, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 408, in _prepare_and_execute       
    await adapt_connection._start_transaction()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 716, in _start_transaction
    self._handle_exception(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 684, in _handle_exception
    raise error
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 714, in _start_transaction
    await self._transaction.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/transaction.py", line 138, in start
    await self._connection.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 318, in execute
    return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 338, in query
RuntimeError: Task <Task pending name='Task-5' coro=<AsyncToSync.main_wrap() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py:270> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py:184]> got Future <Future pending cb=[Protocol._on_waiter_completed()]> attached to a different loop
```

And when I reload for the 3rd time it raises an InterfaceError stating "cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress".

```
Internal Server Error: /sql/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 714, in _start_transaction
    await self._transaction.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/transaction.py", line 138, in start
    await self._connection.execute(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 318, in execute
    return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 323, in query
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 707, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._check_state
asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 479, in execute
    self._adapt_connection.await_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 76, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 129, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 408, in _prepare_and_execute       
    await adapt_connection._start_transaction()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 716, in _start_transaction
    self._handle_exception(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 682, in _handle_exception
    raise translated_error from error
sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.AsyncAdapt_asyncpg_dbapi.InterfaceError: <class 'asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError'>: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 204, in __call__
    return call_result.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 439, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 270, in main_wrap
    result = await self.awaitable(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/src/app/src/sql/views.py", line 12, in view1
    items = await list_accounts(db_session)
  File "/usr/src/app/src/sql/models.py", line 20, in list_accounts
    return await db_session.scalars(select(Account))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 269, in scalars
    result = await self.execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/asyncio/session.py", line 212, in execute
    result = await greenlet_spawn(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 134, in greenlet_spawn
    result = context.throw(*sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1692, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1631, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 325, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1498, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1862, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2043, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1819, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 479, in execute
    self._adapt_connection.await_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 76, in await_only
    return current.driver.switch(awaitable)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_concurrency_py3k.py", line 129, in greenlet_spawn
    value = await result
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 408, in _prepare_and_execute       
    await adapt_connection._start_transaction()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 716, in _start_transaction
    self._handle_exception(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/asyncpg.py", line 682, in _handle_exception
    raise translated_error from error
sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.InterfaceError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError'>: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
[SQL: SELECT account.acct_id, account.name
FROM account]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

## Approach 2: Manually Creating and Closing Session

Here is my code for the Django view by manually managing the session (http://127.0.0.1:8000/sql/2/)

```py
async def view2(request):
    html = '<html><body><ul>'

    db_session: AsyncSession = settings.DB_SESSION_MAKER()

    items = await list_accounts(db_session)

    await db_session.close()

    for item in items:
        html += '<li>' + item.name + '</li>'

    html += '</ul></body></html>'

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

For the first execution, it returns back the correct response as approach 1. After the first execution, I get the RuntimeError in approach 1 and never get the InterfaceError.

## Approach 3: Manually Creating and Closing Session (Not Awaiting Close)

Here is my code for the Django view for manually managing the session and not awaiting the close method (http://127.0.0.1:8000/sql/2/)

```py
async def view2(request):
    html = '<html><body><ul>'

    db_session: AsyncSession = settings.DB_SESSION_MAKER()

    items = await list_accounts(db_session)

    db_session.close() # logs async warning since missing await, but works

    for item in items:
        html += '<li>' + item.name + '</li>'

    html += '</ul></body></html>'

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

All executions always return back the correct response.